# Garbage collection example in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Beta { }

class Alpha {
static Beta b1  ;
Beta b2;
}

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Beta b1 = new Beta();
    Beta b2 = new Beta();
    Alpha a1 = new Alpha();
    Alpha a2 = new Alpha();

    a1.b1 = b1 ;
    a1.b2 = b1 ;
    a2.b2 = b2 ;

    a1 = null ;
    b1 = null;
    b2 = null;

    System.out.println(" Line 1    " + " a1   "  + a1.b1);
    System.out.println(" Line 2    " + " a1   "  + a1.b2);
    System.out.println(" Line 3    " + " a2   " + a2.b2);
    System.out.println(" Line 4    " + " a1   " + a2.b1);
    System.out.println(" Line 5    " + " b1   " + b1);
    System.out.println(" Line 6    " + " b1   " + b2);

  }

 }
```

I am not sure why only a1 object is available for garbage collection in the above program. I am expecting a1 , b1 and b2 to be collected by garbage collector.

As you can see a1 , b1 and b2 were made NULL hence this is making objects to be available for garbage collection. If object is NULL or unreachable by any thread or reference variable it should be collected by garbage collector.

Can someone help me understand the subtleness of the above program with good example and in more precise way ? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't "make an object null" in Java.  You can null out a _reference_ to the object, though.  In any event, you can't really "observe" garbage collection in Java unless you use weak references or the like.

Comment: how did you find out that b1 and b2 are not garbage collected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there is still reference exists to objects pointed by b1 & b2 refrences due to below lines.

```
a1.b1 = b1 ;
a1.b2 = b1 ;
a2.b2 = b2 ;
```

Assume like this:

```
  b1--->BetaObj1
    b2---BetaObj2
    a1---> AlphaObj1
    a2---> AlphaObj2
```

a1.b1 points to b1 that means, there is reference to BetaObj1
a1.b2 points to b1 that means, there is another reference to BetaObj1

(At this point there are 3 references to BetaObj1)

a2.b2 points to b2 that means, there is reference to BetaOBj2

(At this point there are 2 references to BetaObj2)

`a1=null;` makes AlphaObj1 eligible for GC

`b1=null;` makes BetaObj1 reference count to 2, so this object is not eligible for GC

`b2=null;` makes BetaObj2 reference count to 1, so this object is not eligible for GC.

Comment: I like your answer though it is little contradicting with MR Daniel Fischer answer at the bottom of this page.  Assuming                b1----> BetaObj1,                                                   a1.b1----> BetaObj1 and                                         a1.b2---->BetaObj1

Comment: .When a1 = null which reference connection will be cut down to BetaObj1 , is it a1.b1   or  a1.b2   or   b1 .    i am expecting just the b1 and not a1.b1 and a1.b2 from your given answer. When I executed the a1.b2 is throwing NullPointerException , And same thing MR Fischer said.

Comment: Mr Fischer is talking about static b1 instance variable. I know a static instance variable doesnt need instance to access. But why is he saying just because b1 is static a1.b1 will always be exist (may be I am wrong in the last bit but I cant figure out much more than what Mr Fischer is saying about static). Can you please help me understand this concept. I think i am just very close to understand the concept of garbage collection.

Comment: And I am also excepting a1.b1 to throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

- `b2` is not available for gc because there is still a reference `a2.b2` to it
- `b1` is not available for gc because `Alpha.b1` holds a reference to it (`Alpha.b1` is static, don't be confused because it's set using `a1.b1`)

Answer (score 1):

You ought to get a `NullPointerException` here:

```
System.out.println(" Line 1    " + " a1   "  + a1.b1);
System.out.println(" Line 2    " + " a1   "  + a1.b2);
```

At that point, `a1` was already set to `null`, so accessing its member `b2` can't work since it doesn't refer to an object anymore. (Accessing the static `b1` works since that only requires the class, not an instance.)

> As you can see a1 , b1 and b2 were made NULL hence this is making objects to be available for garbage collection.

No, you set some references to these objects to `null`, while other references to those objects exist, as is the case for `b1` and `b2`, these objects cannot be collected yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are several misconceptions here

- The GC only runs when it needs to.  To perform a GC more often than needed would be doing work it doesn't need to.
- `a1.b1` is actually `Alpha.b1` as the instance is not important and can even be `null` using `al.b1` is plain confusing.
- `a1.b2` should throw a NullPointerException as a1 is `null`.
- `Alpha.b1` is set but not cleared anywhere so the object it referenced is not eligible for cleanup. The other objects could be cleaned up but without calling `System.gc();` explicitly, its is highly unlikely it need to be run at the point you might expect.
- `a1` is cleared but `a2` is not so it won't be cleaned up (until the method returns)

Answer (score 0):

**Garbage Collection Example**

```
public class GarbageCollection {

    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception  {
          Runtime rs =  Runtime.getRuntime();
          System.out.println("Free memory in JVM before Garbage Collection = "+rs.freeMemory());
          rs.gc();
          System.out.println("Free memory in JVM after Garbage Collection = "+rs.freeMemory());
       }
}
```

**Program Output:**

Free memory in JVM before Garbage Collection = 62767488

Free memory in JVM after Garbage Collection = 62854120